# How to get room details in an organization using Microsoft graph API. I'm able to get room name and room Id only

Tags: c#, outlook, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph-API to get the details of rooms from the Outlook, but I am getting only the email addresses and the name of a particular room. For other properties like capacity, I am getting `null` values.
 I am using these following API.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/places/microsoft.graph.room

In the below API, I am getting the names and email addresses of rooms (here I am passing user credential)

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/"+ UserId +"/findRooms](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%22+%20UserId%20+%22/findRooms)

Or

> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/me/findRooms

Is there any way to get all the properties of the room?

Comment: Could you tell me what is "for other properties like capacity i am not getting null values" and provide me a screenshot of your error?

Comment: Actually, I'm getting null values. " i am not getting null values " is a grammar mistake 
​​​​​​​

Comment: According to my research, we can use the Exchange Online PowerShell command ```get-mailbox resourcemailbox@xxx.com |fl```  to get the meeting room properties. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-room-mailboxes

Comment: Check this https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-server-2010-room-mailboxes-step-by-step-guide/ also https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-2013-resource-schema-room-equipment-mailboxes/

Comment: @SubhashChalapati Any update for this issue?